# How to create an if else ladder?

Tags: r, if-statement, variables

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
   Study_ID Gender SMI BMI
1      100   Male  45  19
2      200   Male  50  20
3      300 Female  60  25
4      400   Male  42  29
5      500 Female  38  32
6      600 Female  50  20
7      700   Male  35  29
8      800   Male  47  31
9      900 Female  65  25
```

I would like to create a new, binary variable called 'Sarcopenia', where a patient must meet certain criteria to be defined as 'Yes' sarcopenia, or 'No' sarcopenia. The criteria differs for males and females.

My desired output would look something like this:

```
  Study_ID Gender SMI BMI Sarcopenia
1      100   Male  45  19         No
2      200   Male  50  20         No
3      300 Female  60  25         No
4      400   Male  42  29        Yes
5      500 Female  38  32         No
6      600 Female  50  20        Yes
7      700   Male  35  29         No
8      800   Male  47  31        Yes
9      900 Female  65  25         No
```

I've tried to create an if else ladder:

```
data$Sarcopenia<-
if (data$`SMI` < 41 & data$Gender == "Female") {
"Yes"
} else if (data$`SMI` < 53 & data$Gender == "Male" & data$BMI >= 25) {
"Yes"
} else if (data$`SMI` < 43 & data$Gender == "Male" & data$BMI < 25) {
"Yes"
} else {
"No"
}
```

But for some reason, it gives me 'No', for every single patient (even though I know some of them meet the criteria).

What could I be doing wrong?

Reproducible data:

```
data<-data.frame(Study_ID=c("100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800","900"),Gender=c("Male","Male","Female","Male","Female","Female","Male","Male","Female"),SMI=c("45","50","60","42","38","50","35","47","65"),BMI=c("19","20","25","29","32","20","29","31","25"))
```

Comment: your example is not reproducible since there are missing columns in the data frame you provide (SMI,BMI, gender)

Comment: There is `case_when` in the dplyr-package, you should check out the docs which has a lot of examples: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Comment: My mistake, I uploaded the wrong reproducible data. It is now fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running your attempt, R produces a warning: `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

This is because `data$SMI < 41 & data$Gender == "Female"` returns a vector with `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each person in the dataset:

```
> data$SMI < 41 & data$Gender == "Female"
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

In R, `if` is not vectorised, so it doesn't understand this input and just uses the first element of the vector (in your case `FALSE`) and ignores the rest. This is why you see 'No' for everyone.

There is a different function `ifelse` which is vectorised, and will work just fine if you use that instead:

```
data = data.frame(Study_ID = 100*1:9, 
                  Gender = c('Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female'), 
                  SMI = c(45, 50, 60,42,38,50,35,47,65), 
                  BMI = c(19, 20, 25, 29, 32, 20, 29, 31, 25))

data$Sarcopenia<-
ifelse(data$`SMI` < 41 & data$Gender == "Female", "Yes",
ifelse(data$`SMI` < 53 & data$Gender == "Male" & data$BMI >= 25, "Yes",
ifelse(data$`SMI` < 43 & data$Gender == "Male" & data$BMI < 25, "Yes", "No")))

data
  Study_ID Gender SMI BMI Sarcopenia
1      100   Male  45  19         No
2      200   Male  50  20         No
3      300 Female  60  25         No
4      400   Male  42  29        Yes
5      500 Female  38  32        Yes
6      600 Female  50  20         No
7      700   Male  35  29        Yes
8      800   Male  47  31        Yes
9      900 Female  65  25         No
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

data$Sarcopenia <-
  case_when(data$`SMI` < 41 & data$Gender == "Female" ~ "Yes", 
            data$`SMI` < 53 & data$Gender == "Male" & data$BMI >= 25 ~ "Yes",
            data$`SMI` < 43 & data$Gender == "Male" & data$BMI < 25 ~ "Yes", 
            TRUE ~ "No")
```

Or without `dplyr` using `ifelse` (but that is not really an if-else ladder, and definitely less readable)

```r
data$Sarcopenia <- 
  ifelse((data$`SMI` < 41 & data$Gender == "Female") |
           (data$`SMI` < 53 & data$Gender == "Male" & data$BMI >= 25) | 
           (data$`SMI` < 43 & data$Gender == "Male" & data$BMI < 25), "Yes", "No")
```

Comment: Since you have attached the whole `dplyr`, why not using `mutate()` to create the new column? With `mutate`, you no longer need `data$` and your code will become neater.

Answer (score 0):

You should use vectorized `ifelse()` instead of `if...else...`.

```r
transform(data,
  Sarcopenia = ifelse(Gender == "Female" &  SMI < 41 |
                      Gender ==   "Male" & (SMI < 53 & BMI >= 25 | SMI < 43 & BMI < 25),
                      "Yes", "No")
)
```